# What regex to use to get a number from a string that may or may not have a decimal part?

Tags: c#, regex

Example strings

```
asda25asd.56asda
a$asdas23asdas
as$dasd.56asdasd
```

The current best one I have is

```
\$?.*?(?<AmountInt>\d+).*(?<AmountDecimal>\.\d+)?.*
```

but it doesn't capture the .56 in the first string and doesn't work for other strings. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try to always add the language/tool you're using when asking a regex question.

Comment: Why do you have `\$` at start of your regex which is not in your sample data?

Comment: @anubhava - My bad, there could be a dollar sign in the string. Updated the example strings

Comment: Thanks can you also show expected output for each of those example lines?

Comment: @anubhava Basically, it should capture the 25 and .56 int a separate group

Comment: But there is no `$` sign in first line before `25`? Is `$` optional?

Answer (score 1):

Why all the noise? `(?<AmountInt>\d+)(?<AmountDecimal>\.\d+)?` should be enough.

Now, `AmoutInt` is `\d+` so you **must** have an integer figure before the dot. Otherwise use `\d*`

EDIT- OK, I understand better your requirement. But the `.*` between the groups is greedy. Try `.*?`instead.

Comment: The noise is there because there could be any characters between the input. It's basically an edge case that I want to make sure gets captured. The .*? suggestion between groups didn't work.